# Google account login error

Tags: system-error, system

my google account and password is correct but it keeps saying you entered the wrong password or your account has changed. it still has me logged in on the email but this error sign will not go away.

Comment: Seems to be an epidemie again, best guess is trouble with some Google servers (not on your end, on *theres*), as you're [not the first one asking this today](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/83767/16575), or [the second](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/83742/16575) …

Answer (score 0):

Log out of email app, then...

- sign in through appropriate app or..
- try to sign in through your browser

If neither will work then remove your Google account from your device and re-add your account. Remember to back up your device prior to doing this, otherwise your contacts, messages, and few other things will be deleted.

You might have a connection error after adding your account while validating your info, if so go into your YouTube app and login that way.